# RxJs operator with unconditional execution in the end of each iteration

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

**Is there a Rx operator or composition to guarantee some logic execution last per each observable emission?**

Let's assume the following context:

1. endless or continuous sequence
2. conditional logic like `filter()` to skip some emissions
3. some logic in the end of each iteration in a **`doAlways()`**-like operator

Please refer to numbered comments in the code-sample below

**Notes:**

- `finalize()` would require the sequence to terminate (violates p.1)
- `iif()` or regular `if` inside `switchMap()` is an option but makes the code more unreadable

**Code snippet to illustrate:** Step (3) should execute always, per-iteration, last, i.e. we want always start and finish log in a `doAlways()`-like operator instead of `tap()`

```
import { of, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
import { tap, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


const dataService = { update: (z) => of(z /*posts data to back-end*/) };

const sub = interval(1000).pipe(            // <-- (1)
  tap(a => console.log('starting', a)),
  filter(b => b % 100 === 0),               // <-- (2)
  switchMap(c => dataService.update(c)),
  tap(d => console.log('finishing', d))     // <-- (3) should execute always even (2)
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: OP wants the notification to reach `tap` even if it was filtered before. Won't be possible though.

Answer (score 1):

No such operator exists, and that's because it can't exist. Once you filtered out a value, the resulting observable just doesn't emit it anymore. Any operator "downstream" just simply doesnt know about its existence.

To illustrate, you included a switchMap to some service, which depends on the emitted value. For obvious reasons that operator that cannot logically be applied if there is no value to switch on.

You would have to "tag" each value instead of filtering it and defer the filter to after the tap call, but even then scenarios like switching to another observable would require more detailed requirements.

---

Think of the observable as a conveyor belt on which you place items. Each operator is a room through which the belt leads. Inside each room a worker can decide what to do with each item: modify it, take it away, put new items in instead etc. However, each worker only sees what the conveyor belt brings along — they don't know what other rooms came before them or what has been done there.

To achieve what you want, the worker in the last room would have to know about an item that he never received, which would require additional knowledge they don't have.

Comment: Sometimes I think RxJS is just Factorio but more illegible and less debuggable

Comment: I find it extremely comfortable to read compared to more traditional ways :-) Debuggability is a bit of an issue, but I've always managed with tap logging. But personal preferences differ.

Comment: Comfortable for those who know the words, sure ;-)

Comment: However, I was referring to this game: https://www.factorio.com/ One could recreate your analogy in this game. Maybe illegible isn't the best term, let's say "understandable"

Comment: Yes, if you don't understand the concepts or words, it's close to impossible to understand. But I'd prefer having people learn it over rejecting it because of that. I'll check out that link later!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, what you ask is not possible due to the fact that filtered notifications won't ever be passed on. You would need a totally new type of notification that is not consumed by any other operator than the one you describe.

Now, here is an idea that is probably not recommended. You can misuse the `error` notification to skip some operators, but that will interfere with any other error handling so that's not something you should do...

```
const sub = interval(1000).pipe(            
  tap(a => console.log('starting', a)),
  mergeMap(b => b % 100 === 0 ? of(b) : throwError(b)),
  switchMap(c => dataService.update(c)),
  catchError(b => of(b)),
  tap(d => console.log('finishing', d))
)
```

Note that we don't use `filter` but map to either a `next` or an `error` notification depending on the condition. Errors will naturally be ignored by **most** operators and consumed by `tap`, `subscribe` or `catchError`. This is a way to *put a tag on the item so the workers know they shouldn't touch it* (in the analogy described by Ingo)

Comment: That's why the condition reads: "like filter" not "filter". Filter for surely stops any further flow, but the meaning is some way to jump over the undesired for the particular iteration steps without making iif-s or other things making the code too curly. Had .doAlways() -like existed - problem would be solved

Comment: Hm well a single operator couldn't do anything like that, it's more a restriction due to the possible types of notifications

Answer (score 1):

I would split it for 2 streams with `partition`, and them would merge them back.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8z9jit?file=index.ts

```
import { of, interval, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap, partition, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

const dataService = { update: z => of(z /*posts data to back-end*/) };

const [sub, rest] = interval(1000).pipe(
  tap(a => console.log('starting', a)),
  share(),
  partition(b => b % 2 === 0)
);

merge(
    sub.pipe(
      switchMap(c => dataService.update(c)),
      tap(() => console.log('Ok'))
    ), 
    rest
)
.pipe(tap(d => console.log('finishing', d)))
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible work-around is to eliminate the `.filter()` of course.

Given:

```
observable.pipe(
  filter(() => condition),
  switchMap(p => service.otherObservable(p)),
  tap(d => console.log('not triggered when condition is false'))
)
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
observable.pipe(
  switchMap(p =>
   (!condition) ? 
     of(null) : 
     service.otherObservable(p)),
  tap(d => console.log('always triggered'))
)
```